# How to get pixel color of Direct2D bitmap on SharpDX

Tags: c#, directx, direct2d, sharpdx

I use SharpDX and I don't understand how to get pixel color at bitmap. I found CopySubresourceRegion method, but it working on Direct3D.
I've strange idea:

I can create RenderForm and drawing my bitmap on form. Then get graphics of form. Then create bitmap via "new Bitmap(width, height, graphics)". And then get pixel color from new bitmap;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting Direct2D 1.1 (or higher), then you can use the [ID2D1Bitmap1::Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. This will require that you set *D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CPU_READ* and *D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW* [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the bitmap when creating it.

Comment: Thanks! It's realy help me!

Answer (score 3):

I written special function for getting pixel color. This solved my problem ;)
C# - SharpDX

```
Color4 GetPixel(Bitmap image, int x, int y, RenderTarget renderTarget) {
        var deviceContext2d = renderTarget.QueryInterface<DeviceContext>();
        var bitmapProperties = new BitmapProperties1();
        bitmapProperties.BitmapOptions = BitmapOptions.CannotDraw | BitmapOptions.CpuRead;
        bitmapProperties.PixelFormat = image.PixelFormat;
        var bitmap1 = new Bitmap1(deviceContext2d, new Size2((int)image.Size.Width, (int)image.Size.Height), bitmapProperties);
        bitmap1.CopyFromBitmap(image);
        var map = bitmap1.Map(MapOptions.Read);
        var size = (int)image.Size.Width * (int)image.Size.Height * 4;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(map.DataPointer, bytes, 0, size);
        bitmap1.Unmap();
        bitmap1.Dispose();
        deviceContext2d.Dispose();
        var position = (y * (int)image.Size.Width + x) * 4;
        return new Color4(bytes[position], bytes[position + 1], bytes[position + 2], bytes[position + 3]);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the fact that although this method is working, it'll be extremely slow if you try to read multiple pixels. For reading multiple pixels, you should copy (download) the pixel data once to a temporary buffer and then perform sequential reading from the temporary buffer. Just to point out for sake of clarity a good way to do pixel-oriented operations is to use shaders to make custom effects (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Though I'm not sure that the effects API is not overcomplicated in D2D.

Comment: Yes, I know than it method is non performance. In my project I save bytearray of bitmap and get pixels from this. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for an efficient way of getting pixels from a Bitmap,
I have written a class that clones and maps a bitmap, provides direct access to the generated DataRectangle (aka pixel data), and finally automatically unmaps the bitmap.

```cs
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;

public unsafe class ReadableBitmap
{
    private readonly Bitmap1 origin;
    private readonly Color32* pixels;
    private readonly int pitch;

    public Size2 Size { get; private set; }

    public Color32 this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= Size.Width || y >= Size.Height)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Cannot get a pixel outside of the bitmap.");

            var rowPtr = (Color32*)((byte*)pixels + y * pitch);
            return rowPtr[x];
        }
    }

    public ReadableBitmap(RenderTarget target, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var deviceContext2d = target.QueryInterface<DeviceContext>();
        var bitmapProperties = new BitmapProperties1
        {
            BitmapOptions = BitmapOptions.CannotDraw | BitmapOptions.CpuRead,
            PixelFormat = bitmap.PixelFormat
        };

        Size = bitmap.PixelSize;
        origin = new Bitmap1(deviceContext2d, Size, bitmapProperties);

        deviceContext2d.Dispose();

        origin.CopyFromBitmap(bitmap);
        var map = origin.Map(MapOptions.Read);
        pitch = map.Pitch;
        pixels = (Color32*)map.DataPointer;

        origin.Disposing += OnBitmapDisposing;
    }

    private static void OnBitmapDisposing(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not Bitmap1 bmp)
            return;

        bmp.Unmap();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct Color32
    {
        public byte R;
        public byte G;
        public byte B;
        public byte A;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var read = new ReadableBitmap(renderTarget, bitmap);
Console.WriteLine($"The top left pixel has an alpha of {read[0, 0].A}.");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).